# JavaScript AJAX chat - The popular date ASC scroll issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have already had a stackoverflow question about this, but the answer was no proper enough, and this time I want to explain more in a different way of what I want, for a different product.

First of all, how should AJAX chat messages get loaded?

- Do I need to send an AJAX request every a few milliseconds to check if there are new messages, and then load the new messages if exists using timestamps? Or do I just need to reload all messages and replace the div with the new message list every a few milliseconds?

**The problem**

Okay, my chat is currently loading all messages every 5,000 milliseconds. 
So when a new message is being posted and the chat reloads, the scroll will stay on the same position, and a new message will go down below.

As you see, on stackoverflow chat, it's somehow automatically goes up, when a new message appears, somehow a new message slides at the bottom of the chat, and the old messages just goes above it without any scrolling, yet the scroll gets bigger & I can scroll up to see older messages.

**Dirty solution 1:** Making the scroll scroll down to bottom upon reload, which is really annoying.

**Final solution:** Checking if user's scroll is located at the bottom, if yes - load the new messages and scroll down right away. If the scroll is not located at the bottom of the chat, the chat will not scroll down.

But these solutions are very bad, I want to do something like stackoverflow chat does, it slides the new messages perfectly, without any scrolling.

*Is there a **valid solution** for this problem? I assume I am not the only whom is having this problem.*

Comment: If you talk about chatting, mostly pointing to realtime, so why don't you use sockets instead of requesting all messages every 5 seconds?

Comment: Can you please link me to an example? heard about it

Comment: using jQuery: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-create-a-simple-web-based-chat-application/ or using php sockets: http://www.flynsarmy.com/2012/02/php-websocket-chat-application-2-0/